# Items not spanning across multiple columns HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm simply trying to display some posts from a database, which are basically just some blocks of text, across multiple columns, depending on the size of the browser.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
        body{
        column-count: 3;
        column-fill: balance;
        }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
        body{
        column-count: 2;
        }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
        body{
        column-count: 1;
        }
}
```

Here's what I have for my CSS at the moment. I can tell it's working because when I resize the browser my content gets squished. For full screen it's only in the first 1/3 of the windows, for mid-size it's on the left half, and for small it takes up the whole browser. So I can see this is somewhat working, but the problem is that my posts don't actually span across multiple columns. They're always just forced in the first column.

Comment: Can we see it somewhere?

Comment: Show it in a fiddle svp

Comment: you have to have something wrong with your html .. if I put pure text into body with no other tags, your CSS is working 100% correct (I have only altered some sizes because of jsfiddle smaller output window, try dragging the divider and see) https://jsfiddle.net/m02dvj28/

Comment: I can reproduce the problem if I take @Zorak's fiddle, remove most of the text from it AND add `body {height:100vh}` to the CSS.

Comment: yes, but I believe it should work like that, because you have text in body with 1, 2 or 3 columns, but the text is shorter even that one column with given height, so it has no reason to continue in second column as it didnt fill even the first one ... so the problem here is probably that @Birdman has to alter height of the container inside which is the text ...